# NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I keep getting this error when I try to sign up on my application, I am using devise for authentication;

```
    NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new


undefined method `registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe45c6c35e8>:0x007fe45d9ffd78>
Extracted source (around line #3):

  <h2>Sign up</h2>

  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
```

When I run `rake routes` I get;

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Sign up link code;

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path%>
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to ParaPenguin the sign up field works now, but when I click submit I keep getting this problem

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"

    new_user_session_path    GET     /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
user_session_path    POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path    DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
user_password_path   POST    /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
new_user_password_path   GET     /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password_path  GET     /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
PATCH    /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
PUT  /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration_path    GET     /users/cancel(.:format)     devise/registrations#cancel
user_registration_path   POST    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration_path   GET     /users/sign_up(.:format)    devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration_path  GET     /users/edit(.:format)   devise/registrations#edit
PATCH    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
PUT  /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
DELETE   /users(.:format)
```

**Update 2-Gjaldon asked me to include my user model and routes**
My user model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Routes.rb

```
Document::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
   root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
   get "prices" => "pages#prices"
  get "faq" => "pages#faq", :as => :faq
  get "terms" => "pages#terms"
  get "view" => "pages#view"
  get "policy" => "pages#policy"
  get "contact" => "pages#contact"
  get "works" => "pages#works"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you provide your routes for Devise in your routes.rb and the devise code for your User model?

It's either one of the following that might fix your problem:

1. Restart your Rails server. This way, Rails will see the new files and changes Devise has made to Rails.
2. Did you override the Devise::Registrations#new action? If so, you will need to replace your view code below:

`<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`

with:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
```

In your `devise_registrations/edit.html.erb` view, your form_for code would look like:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => edit_user_registration_path(resource_name, :method => :put) do |f| %>
```

Your `rake routes` actually provides you with the routes you need to submit to. Just keep in mind that the corresponding controller and action is displayed under the Controller#action column in the output of `rake routes`. The form in `edit` action should always submit to the `update` action and the form in `new` action should always submit to the `create` action if you stick to the Rails conventions. If you decide to have a form in another action for creating a record, then make sure to have the form submit to the `create` action.

Comment: I did that, I still keep getting No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"

Comment: Just realized I provided the wrong path. I've edited my answer to reflect the correct url.

Comment: Sorry, for continuing to ask you questions, I really appreciate it.   Do you know if the code for signing in would be in the registrations edit.html.erb and if it is, would it be 
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>

Comment: Note to self: always restart local rails sever before troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `registration_path(resource_name)` from

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

to `new_registration_path(resource_name)`. This could fix the error but I am not certain, it's possible. It seems that it is only for you as that file setup runs just fine for my devise.